# Unable to create process using Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-10, command-prompt

I installed anaconda, it was working properly until I tried to pip install superset, and got this error:
Unable to create process using Anaconda 'C:\Users<username>\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users<username>\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" '

now neither conda nor pip work on my computer (I get this error when I try "conda" or "pip" in my prompt), anyone faced the same issue?

1. I tried uninstall and reinstalling anaconda and readded the environment variables but to no luck
2. when I type "where conda" in the anaconda prompt, I get this:

C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat

3. I tried uninstalling pip it was uninstalled successfully, but when I tried to install with
   "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" I got this:

C:\Users<username>\anaconda3\python.exe: No module named pip

however, I was able to install it manually from here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/
now pip works, but conda still doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. Been using conda for months just fine. Then, I deactivated my conda environment, installed an older version of Python outside of conda, created a `venv` in my project directory, and attempted to install various modules with `pip`. My conda broke, permanently, in much the same way as you're describing. Complete reinstall did not fix the issue. Got the same error message as you.

If I had to guess, I'd say your `<username>` dir contains space characters. Notice the error message: `C:\Users<username>\anaconda3\python.exe` is not wrapped in quotes like it should be, meaning conda will choke if the  dir contains spaces. Conda is supposed to be able to handle spaces so that it can work on Windows; however, messing around with `pip` and deactivating all conda environments might break that behaviour permanently somehow. Don't ask me how or why.

I would recommend reinstalling conda to another directory, ideally in `C:/anaconda3`. This fixed the issue for me.