Python already installed still getting error "Unable to process..." while creating new environment in anaconda prompt

Tried to change the python version to 3.8 but still facing the same issue.
Thanks in advance!!
Tried to create a new environment to test open ai api key but showing error(shared screenshot above).Also if there's any open source compiler where i can do this please share

Looking at your error, I note that the path to python.exe includes a directory with spaces in the name and is not in quotes unlike the parameter that is passed.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76119773/unable-to-create-process-using-anaconda for what might be bad news.

Try this command:

conda create --name myenv python=3.7

After using this command, try to activate your environment using:

conda activate myenv

and then check your version.
If you don't want to create new environment then try to uninstall your python app and download the 3.7 version from this website.
